# How can i make 2 teams?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've tried out everything to get 2 Teams, 1 Red, 1 Blue.
But I can't seem to figure it out?

I tried to do scoreboard etc. but it didn't work.
How do I create two teams when 2 players join and the game begins.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: You tried to do scoreboard? What exactly does that mean?

Answer (score 2):

For your teams question, you can create teams using the `/scoreboard teams add <team>` command. For example:

```
/scoreboard teams add TeamName1
/scoreboard teams add TeamName2
```

You can then set their colors using `/scoreboard teams option <team> color <color>`. For example:

```
/scoreboard teams option TeamName1 color blue
/scoreboard teams option TeamName2 color red
```

Comment: But how can i do that when a player clicks a button they are in a team? cause now it doesnt work.